# One day trip to London for a South-African citizen

Tags: visas, london, paris, south-african-citizens

I am travelling to Portugal and Paris in December. I am from South Africa and will be flying on a Schengen Visa. We want to do a day trip on the Eurostar from Paris to London. What are the visa requirements I would need?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the requirements are exactly the same as if you would want to travel to the UK for a month as a tourist. There are some rules about transit but no exemptions for day trips or for Schengen visa holders. And trains to the UK are treated like flights into the country, which means passport check and security inspection prior to boarding.

In your case, it means that you also [need a visa for the UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/tourism).

Comment: If it's approved, the OP will get the full six months anyway.  Possibly capped to sync with the Schengen...

Comment: You can remove "As far as I know", the answer is fine, up-to-date, blah blah blah.  No need to qualify it :)

Comment: @GayotFow Advice on what visa somebody needs is almost legal advice: gentle disclaimers seem appropriate.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, information on this site does not constitute 'legal advice', at least for matters arising under UK immigration law.  See http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1999/33/contents

Comment: @GayotFow I mean "legal advice" in the loose sense that the question is essentially "What does the law say about X?" and the answer is "To the best of my knowledge, it is legal to do Y and Z."

Comment: @DavidRicherby, that's certainly a 'loose sense'; a VERY loose sense. There is no need for a caveat or qualification for a 'loose sense'. Imagine "...I have no idea what I'm talking about, but it's legal..."  :)  Officiousness.